# Django Rest Framework value id is being sent, but is being received as null

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Having an issue where I am trying to set the `interest_category`. Here is my current code.

**Serializer**

```
class ProjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    interest_category = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        read_only_fields = (
            'created_by',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ),
        fields = (
            'project_title',
            'project_description',
            'interest_category',
        )
```

**Model**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    project_description = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    interest_category = models.ForeignKey(Interests, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='projects', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Views**

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProjectsSerializer
    queryset = Project.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

**Here is the data being sent**

```
{
    "project_title": "Test",
    "project_description": "Test1",
    "interest_category": 2
}
```

**Here is the data being received**

```
(35, Test, Test1, 2022-09-22 02:11:54.342202+00, 2022-09-22 02:11:54.342202+00, 1, null).
```

**I can send the data without a null error when I am NOT using the `interest_category = serializers.StringRelatedField()` in the serializer.**

**Any ideas why the `interest_category` is showing `null` and why it is not being sent and/or received correctly when using the `serializers.StringRelatedField()`?**

**And if it is because of the `StringRelatedField` is there a better way to get the name while posting the ID? In frontend, I am passing the ID as a value.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `interest_category = serializers.StringRelatedField()` put
`interest_category = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)` because `StringRelatedField` may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its `__str__` method. Where `IntegerField` representation An integer.

because you sending integer value in data :

```
{
    "project_title": "Test",
    "project_description": "Test1",
    "interest_category": 2
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but when calling the API I am not getting/showing the name of the item.